# Facebook JS SDK prevents DOM element from being modified

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

The Facebook JS SDK is redrawing my "Sign in by Facebook" button everytime I edit it via jQuery.

Let's me describe the problem's scenario:

I've made my own "Sign in by Facebook" button with HTML & CSS (Thus, i'm not using default login by facebook plugin button).

```
<button id='signin-by-facebook' class='js-facebook-connect' type='button'>
    <i class='icon icon-svg-facebook'></i>
    <span>Sign in with <strong>Facebook</strong></span>
</button>
```

When the DOM is ready, I attach an "onclick" handler which calls FB's SDK login() function, and applies jQuery().prop('disabled', true) to it, so far so good, the button is getting disabled as expected.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#signin-by-facebook').click(function(event)
    {
        var _this = $(this);

        // Let's disable the button 
        // while login popup is active
        _this.prop('disabled', true);
        FB.login(function(response)
        {
             if (response.authResponse)
             {
                   // OK
                   [...]
             }

             else
             {
                 // Error...
                 // (I know it's not always error,
                 // but will do for the example)

                 _this.prop('disabled', false);
                 console.log('This is called!');
             }
        }
    });
});
```

Now the problem begins. If for some reason the user closes the FB login popup, the error callback is executing jQuery().prop('disabled', false) but the button is still disabled!

I've came to the conclusion that FB's SDK is redrawing/preventing the button to be altered in some odd way.

I've searched over all the internet for a solution but i've found nothing.

So, my question is:
**Once the button is disabled with jQuery.prop('disabled', false), how can I re-enable it?**
(jQuery.removeProp()/removeAttr() aren't also working)

Hope you can help me... and sorry for the long post!

Many Thanks!

Comment: I doubt that your conclusion is actually correct. Please show an actually testable live example.

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/vebyqr8s/15/
But you must set it locally, because of FB SDK is forbidding iframe sandboxing